# Graph based set cover problem

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph based set cover problem where sets are graphs.
Given a graph G=(V,E) and G1, G2,..Gn subgraphs of G; The question is to find the minimum set of subgraphs whose  union is equal to G.

Although I am new to this area, I spent a fair amount of time searching for such formulation without success, which is odd.

I also realize that a *trivial* solution would be to only consider the edges as elements and solve a classical set cover problem.

However, in large graphs, there can be orders of magnitude more edges than vertices, which is bad for the approximation. Hence I am curious if this problem was ever considered, and if we can improve the approximation by taking into account the vertices.
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *subgraphs*? Are you talking about vertex-induced subgraphs, edge-induced subgraphs, spanning subgraphs, or subgraphs?

Comment: I guess it will depend on the chosen graph $G$ (?)

Comment: And what does *reconstitute* mean?

Comment: The union of the chosen subgraphs = G

Comment: May I add that the subgraphs are simply included in G; should I specify that vertices and edges have identifiers? This is not a “shape” fitting problem.

Comment: You really do need to specify if there's anything special about the subgraphs. If they can be arbitrary subgraphs of $G$, then this is *just* a set cover problem in disguise: knowing whether $e_1$ is an edge of a subgraph $G_2$ doesn't tell you anything about a different edge $e_2$, so the graph formulation tells you nothing.

Comment: @MishaLavrov agreed; I am just wondering whether considering vertices (in addition to edges) can play some role in finding the cover.